# How to rewrite urls such as example.com/1Bta62 to example.com/view.aspx?id=1Bta62 whilst the user still sees example.com/1Bta62?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

As part of an url shortening service, I need users to be able to go to an url such as [example.com/1Bta62](http://example.com) and end up at [example.com/view.aspx?id=1Bta62](http://example.com) whilst the [example.com/1Bta62](http://example.com) is maintained in their browser address bar. How can this be done?

I am using a windows server (project is C# ASP.NET); I would prefer to not have to use scripts (i.e. just something in web.config would be great) but welcome answers of any method. The url endings such as the one above [1Bta62](http://example.com) are dynamically generated.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Has anyone actually managed/knows how to do this with the web.config file - I think it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **[Url Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)**, which has been designed to do just that. It's an IIS module that requires no changes to be done to the app.

> IIS URL Rewrite 2.0 enables Web administrators to create powerful
>   rules to implement URLs that are easier for users to remember and
>   easier for search engines to find. By using rule templates, rewrite
>   maps, .NET providers, and other functionality integrated into IIS
>   Manager, Web administrators can easily set up rules to define URL
>   rewriting behavior based on HTTP headers, HTTP response or request
>   headers, IIS server variables, and even complex programmatic rules. In
>   addition, Web administrators can perform redirects, send custom
>   responses, or stop HTTP requests

Update:

Take a look at RouteMagic:
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/30/introducing-routemagic.aspx

Comment: This does look very interesting, I am using a shared hosting service - would I be able to use this without having any control over IIS?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Updated answer

Answer (score -1):

Please try registering the routes in area registration. For e.g.,

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Myproject_default",
            "Myproject/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Myproject", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: How could I implement areas to solve the problem (I think it is possible)?